# How to Break the line and make new line only after specified character ( ";" in my case ) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, newline, line-breaks

I want to break the line and make a new line in `UITableViewCell`. That too only after specified character [;]

```
   // the code im using is
   loadLbl.numberOfLines=0;
   loadLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

But with this, I am not getting exactly what I want.

I want to break the line only after ;

Comment: Can you please specify, what is your input line and how you want the output?

Comment: try with `replacingOccurrences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Objective-C]

Use [replace method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofst?language=objc)

Code:

```
NSString *text = @"text;with;string";
NSString *newText = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@";\n"];
```

Result:

```
text;
with;
string
```

Comment: But i want to go to next line only when there is no enough place.  @arts

Like   text; with; the;
          String ;

Comment: You need calculate text width. Can help NSString method `sizeWithAttributes:`
`NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName = (NSFont *)font}; CGSize textSize = [self sizeWithAttributes:attributes];` if `textSize` more you textLabel when need next line @Ravi